# Como inicializo una variable que guarde el valor de un input type:password en php?

Tags: php

**Al inicializar la variable pass de esta forma :**
:

```
<?php 
   $pass= htmlspecialchars($_POST['pass']); 
?>
```

**Me salta el error:**

> Undefined array key

Comment: Para ver lo que recibes en $_POST, puedes hacer un var_dump($_POST) y ver el contenido.

Comment: Teniendo un formulario como este

 ` <form action="action.php">
        <input type="password" name="pass" id="">
        <input type="submit" >
    </form>
`

Y haciendo `echo var_dump($_POST)` 

Obtengo:

`DATA array(0) { }`